# Distinct values in groups in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

I want to get all the values that are distinct in that group. For eg:

```
Group | Value
1     | a
1     | b
1     | a
1     | c
2     | a
2     | b
2     | b
3     | a
```

Desired Result: (format may vary)

```
Group | Value
1     | a
1     | b
1     | c
2     | a
2     | b
3     | a
```

OR

```
Group | Value
1     | {a,b,c}
2     | {a,b}
3     | {a}
```

Distinct (group, value) pairs can be found, but how can I find distinct within that group only.

Comment: Funy that you mention the word `DISTINCT` three times and have not been able to find the simple solution `SELECT DISTINCT`. Look at your first result. You say: "Distinct (group, value) pairs can be found, but how can I find distinct within that group only.", but what would be the differnce? The overall distinct rows are the same rows you get when looking at distinct values per group.

Answer (score 0):

The first output is simply:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM my_table
ORDER BY "Group", "Value";
```

The second output is:

```
SELECT "Group", array_agg(DISTINCT "Value" ORDER BY "Value") AS "Value"
FROM my_table
GROUP BY "Group"
ORDER BY "Group";
```

Comment: You forgot the `GROUP BY` clause in the second query. And the `ORDER BY` clauses should probably include the value, too.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for the heads-up on the `GROUP BY` in the second form. The OP did not ask about ordering but have added that to ensure identical results to those given.